# Gitlab CI /CD: Cannot override private project npm package registry URL for dependencies

Tags: docker, vue.js, npm, gitlab

I was wondering if someone could help me with my CI/CD configuration for a multi-JS project setup.

Project `js-core` has some core JS libaries, and project `vue-core` has some reusable vue components. They are both published as npm packages to the "js-core" project's repository (so that we can use a deploy token with `npm publish`, as opposed to using a group deploy token, where you have to script the package creation and push directly to the API).

`vue-core` has a dependency of `js-core`, so it needs to access the npm package registry of the `js-core` project to download it inside of the Docker CI/CD instance.

However, gitlab does not allow me to override the package registry's URL. According to some google research, setting the values with `yarn config set @myorg:registry <gitlab-url>` / `yarn config set //gitlab.com/api/v4/...  <deploy token>` or `npm config set @myorg:registry <gitlab-url>` / `npm config set //gitlab.com/api/v4/... <deploy token>` should work. However I can see that **it is still trying to download the packages from the `vue-core` package registry**, even though it is **disabled as a feature** there.

This is the part of my .gitlab-ci.yml that runs before it fails:

```
image: node:17-alpine

stages:
  - build
  - test

before_script:
  - yarn config set @myorg:registry https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${NPM_PACKAGES_PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/
  - yarn config set //gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${NPM_PACKAGES_PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/:_authToken ${NPM_PACKAGES_PROJECT_TOKEN}
  - yarn install
```

It fails at `yarn install` with:

```
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<vue-core_project_id>/packages/npm/@myorg/js-core/-/@myorg/js-core-1.0.0.tgz: Request failed \"404 Not Found\"".
```

Where the project ID should be the value of `<js-core_project_id>`.

I have tried writing to all possible `.npmrc` file paths (`~/.npmrc`, `./.npmrc`, `${CI_BUILD_DIR}/.npmrc`, setting the values with `npm config set` and `yarn config set`, deactivating the `packages` feature in the gitlab project itself. I have also not found any predefined environment variables that would override my configs (see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html). `@myorg` is correct and matches the gitlab url, as the actual value for "myorg" is a single word...

I am pretty much out of ideas at this point, any help is appreciated!

**Update 1:** I don't think it is a npm / yarn issue, maybe a gitlab caching problem? If I execute `npm config ls -l` and `yarn config list` the correct URLs are output in a format that works locally. I will attempt to clear the yarn cache (globally and locally) and pray that that works.

Comment: I had not touched my project in 5 mnts, updated some stuff and ran CI again, fails with 404 can't find the private repo. This worked before. Not anymore. It was a huge headache to get yarn working before and just wasted another day farting around with it.

I started migrating away from Yarn a while ago because of these headaches. The resolution for me, again here was to stop using yarn, and just use npm.